# How many different positive integers can be obtained as a sum of some or all off the numbers: $1,3,5,10,25$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many different positive integers can be obtained as a sum of some or all of the numbers:
$1,3,5,10,25$?

I have just started discrete mathematics and I am having problems with some tasks. This is one of them. I don't really know what should be my starting approach. Could someone explain how to solve a problem like this one?

Comment: Hint: $1<3, 1+3<5, 1+3+5<10, 1+3+5+10<25.$

Comment: So you aren't allowed to use any number twice?

Comment: As far as I remember I am not.

Comment: In which case there are $32$ possible sums-- either you include $m$ or you don't, so $2$ options for each of the $5$ numbers.  Now its a matter of seeing if any $j+k+... = m$ and that will use amWhys hint.

Comment: It helps to remark that it is clear that no two sums can coincide.  To see this, note that each number is greater than the sum of all the numbers beneath it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Notice that all possible sums are distinct so we can restate the problem as "how many non-empty subsets does $\{1,3,5,10,25\}$ have?" because for each element, we either include it to sum or not.

Comment: $ \binom{5}{1} * \binom{5}{2} * \binom{5}{3} * \binom{5}{4} * \binom{5}{5}$ is it somehow close to the result?

Comment: But it may be possible that different subsets have the same sum.

Comment: @JamesSmith It should be $\binom{5}{1}+\binom{5}{2}+\binom{5}{3}+\binom{5}{4}+\binom{5}{5}$ and this is the number of proper subsets, yes.

Comment: Right it should be $+$. So now as @Ihf mentioned there might be some sums that give us same result?

Comment: @lhf Well, even though it was brute force, I checked whether there are two subsets with the same sum or not. Since I checked that, I said "all possible sums are distinct".

Comment: @JamesSmith Actually we can also prove that with some logical arguments. For example when we sum $1,3,5,10$, we get $19$ and $19<25$ so we should check whether there are two subsets with the same sum of the set $\{1,3,5,10\}$. Here, by a similar argument, we have $1+3+5 = 9 < 10$ so we should check the same thing for $\{1,3,5\}$. And if we continue like that, we can see that there are no two subsets which have the same sum.

Comment: IMO there are two things on has to realize:  One: the writing of the sums are 1-1 with the subsets. And Two: since 1 <3; 1+3< 5; 1+3+5 < 10; etc. this means that the two different writing of sums can't equal the same number.

Comment: A much easier way to figure out the number of proper subsets rather than adding the "chooses" is to realize for each element either can be or not be in a subset.  So for each element there are $2$ choices so the number of subsets is $2^{|S|}$.  And the number of non-empty subsets (nitpick: the entire set, though not a proper subset, will make a proper sum) is $2^{|s|} - 1$.

Comment: ""how many proper subsets does {1,3,5,10,25} have?"  Nitpick:  $1+3+5+10+25$ is an acceptable sum although {1,3,5,10,25} is not a proper subset.  $0 = 0$ is not an accpetabl sum an $\emptyset$ is not a proper subset.  Perhaps a more accurate way to put this is "How many non-empty subsets does {1,3,5,10,25} have". ... just a minor nitpick.

Comment: @fleablood Oh, that's right, I confused the definitions, thank you for the correction.

Comment: It's a *very* minor nitpick.

Answer (score 2):

A sum is of the form $a*1 + b*3 + c*5 + d*10 + e*25$ where $a,b,c,d,e$ are either $0$ or $1$.  There are $2$ choices for each $a,b,c,d,e$ so there are $2^5 = 32$ possible sums.  But $0+0+0+0+0 = 0$ is not acceptable so there are only $2^5 - 1 = 31$ possible sums.

But we need to worry about if there are two different ways of writing sums that add to the same number.

$1 + 3 + 5 + 10 = 19 < 25$ so if the sum is more than or equal to $25$ then $e$ must be $1$ and if the sum is less then $25$  then $e$ must be $0$ so if two different sums add to the some thing then the $e$ value in each sum must be the same.

So if $a*1 + b*3 + 5*c + 10*d + 25*e = h*1 + i*3+k*5 + l*10 + m*25$ then $e=m$ and $a*1 + b*3 + c*5 + d*10 = h*1 + i*3 + k*5 +l*10 = N$.

We do the same argument again.  $1 + 3 + 5 = 9 < 10$ so if $N \ge 10$ then $d=l=1$ and if $N < 10$ then $d=l=0$ and we have

$a*1 + b*3 + c*5 = h*1 +i*3 + k*5 = M$ and as $1 + 3 = 4 < 5$ we have $c = k$ and as $1 < 3$ we have $b = i$ and therefore $a=h$.

So any possible number can be reached only one way.  So there are $31$ distinct sums.

....

It's worth thinking about writing them out and comparing them to the binary representations of $1$ to $31$.  It should build intuition:

$1 = 1_2 \to 1$

$2 = 10_2 \to 3$

$3 = 11_2 \to 3+1 = 4$

$4 = 100_2 \to 5 = 5$

$5 = 101_2 \to 5 + 1 = 6$

....

$29 = 11101_2 \to 25 + 10 + 5 + 1 = 41$

$30 = 11110_2 \to 25 + 10 + 5 + 3 = 43$

$31 = 11111_2 \to 25 + 10 + 5 + 3 + 1 = 44$.

It's interesting that there are only $13$ numbers that aren't possible.  We can't get $2$ so we can get any $25*a + 10*b + 5*c + 2$ so that rules out, $2,7,12,...,42$ and that accounts for $9$ of the numbers.  The rest are that $20... 24$ are impossible.

Comment: I'm trying to think of the most intuitive an plain talking argument why $1 < 3; 1+3 < 5; 1+3+5 < 10;$ and $1 + 3 + 5+10 < 25$ means we can't have two ways of expressing the same number.  It's clear if you think about it and that's the intuition math student develop but... How can we teach it.

Comment: "To see this, note that each number is greater than the sum of all the numbers beneath it." -@lulu..... Oh.  That is a good way of putting it.

Answer (score 1):

By the PigeonHole Principle, any set of numbers whose cardinality is greater than or equal to $10$, has two proper subsets with the same sum.

Obviously, no two numbers of this group have the same sum. So the total amount of numbers is the total number of combinations. Assuming that the numbers can be only sums, the number is

$^5\text C_2+^5\text C_3+^5\text C_4+^5\text C_5$.

This can also be expressed as $2^5-5$.

Comment: You need to look "sums" of just one number, they count too.  Also the sum of combination numbers is $2^5-6$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi `...sum of some or all numbers..`